# How to make Apostrophe CMS recognize renamed home.html?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Just discovering Apostrophe and working on the first project.
I'm using Webstorm IDE and installed twig plugin to add support for Nunjuks in the editor. Unfortunately the only way to make it work was to rename home.html (and other templates) to home.twig.html. But now the site throws an error as it cannot find home.html. Changing name: 'home' to name: 'home.twig" in the apostrophe-pages/index.js did not work. Is there another place where i can change the setting to make Apostrophe recognize template_name.twig.html files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a github ticket to work on support for the .njk extension, which is the official documented extension for nunjucks and probably also works with your editor.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue.  IDE works with any extension that's setup.  The problem is that Apostrophe is not picking up home template with a different extension.  How to tell Apostrophe to look for renamed templates?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is a github ticket *for Apostrophe* to support the .njk extension side by side with .html, which presumably would be good enough for your needs.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Got it.  That would work.

Comment: There's a fix for this in this PR:

https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe/pull/1026

Feel free to help review & evaluate. It's likely to get published in the next week or so.

The behavior implemented here is "regardless of whether the programmer asked for .html, .njk or didn't specify, try .njk first, then .html." This allows you to choose .njk when overriding, even though we chose .html for our stock templates. There's a configurable option to change up the extensions list.